# resample() in python error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I am picking up Python....trying to use resample and getting below error
referring https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes

```
from sklearn.utils import resample

df_majority = df[df.balance==0]
df_minority = df[df.balance==1]
#Upsample minority class
df_minority_upsampled = resample(df_minority, 
                                 replace=True,     # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=576,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=123) # reproducible results
=================
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 253, in resample
    max_n_samples, n_samples))
ValueError: Cannot sample 576 out of arrays with dim 49
```

Appreciate any help...pointers..
Thank you

P.S: I am using Zeppelin notebook to try these out.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite certain it has to do with your version of sklearn.
    `assert sklearn.__version__ >= 0.18`
will probably result in an Exception the way it is now. :)

Comment: so update it and your problem is solved. :) they only allowed upsampling since 0.18. 2 April 2016 update

Comment: Ok..will try to upgrade....checked downsampling in 0.17 ..it works fine.. :-)..Thank you.